# What's the proper expanded form of RGB and HSL?

Tags: punctuation, acronyms

I know they mean "Red Green Blue" and "Hue Saturation Lightness", but the Wikipedia articles on each refer to them as "red, green, blue", and "hue-saturation-lightness".  Which way, if either, is correct?

Comment: Luminance not lightness

Comment: There’s also _Red/Green/Blue_ and _Hue/Saturation/Lightness_. @Jim Unless I am misinformed, the L in _HSL_ is indeed lightness, not luminance—that’s _HSLum_, which is much less common (I’ve only ever seen it mentioned, never actually come across it in the wild). [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699781) specifically deals with converting between HSL and HSLum, so if I am misinformed, I’m not the only one.

Comment: The Internet certainly won't help settle the _lightness_ versus _luminance_ question, since searches on both spelled-out forms yield instances where the abbreviation is given as _HSL_. Nevertheless, for what little it's worth, matches for "hue saturation lightness" outnumber matches for "hue saturation luminance" by (allegedly) a count of 94,400 to 23,200.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet- Hmm, I'd never even heard "lightness" as a possibility until just now.  I've always referred to it as Luminance as do such authorities as [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WS46B0BFFC-868B-4f96-A182-418D53FD83FF.html) and  [Anaheim Scientific](http://anaheimscientific.com/products/color-analyzer/H500-rgb-color-analyzer.html)

Comment: Having worked in a television studio many years back, I cannot recall that there was ever a tendency to capitalize red/green/blue when discussing the internals of the studio equipment.  (Never worked much with HSL in those terms.)

Answer (score 4):

David South, *The Computer and Information Science and Technology Abbreviations and Acronyms Dictionary* (1994) doesn't have an entry for *HSL*, but its entry for *RGB* is instructive:

> **RGB** Red-Green-Blue {or Red/Green/Blue; Red, Green and Blue} (A mixing model, or method of describing colors {the three primary color signals}, used with many color monitors)

This treatment, giving multiple ways of punctuating the spelled-out form of RGB, strongly suggests that there has never been anything like real-world consensus on how to punctuate the *red*, *green*, and *blue* of *RGB*. I suspect that the same is true of the *hue*, *saturation*, and *lightness* (or *luminance*) of *HSL*.

You are correct, I think, to see the Wikipedia handling of "red, green, blue" on the one hand and "hue-saturation-lightness" on the other as inconsistent—but that merely points up the lack of a relevant style guideline rigorously enforced across Wikipedia's huge number of article pages. Within a less vast book or article, it would be desirable (and less excusable not) to settle on a style for handling terms of this type and then to stick with it.